# Array to string conversion CI session

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I used get_defined_vars() to see what variables i have, and it's result: `CI_Session Object ( [userdata] => Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1449533357 [steam] => Array ( [steam_id] => 76561198260524695 ) [lang] => pl )`. I want to recall the steam_id to variable and i used `echo $this->session->userdata('steam');`, but it's calling a error like: "Array to string conversion". What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to access the `steam_id` variable:

```
$array = $this->session->userdata('steam');
echo $array['steam_id'];
```